# htmll lang="de" but admin page in English

Tags: multisite, html, multi-language

I've set up a multisite Wordpress installation, because I want to work with multipul languages. Everything work except the lang attribute. I want the admin panel to be English, but I want to give lang attribute the value of the language of the site it self (for example german). The only way I see to that is to change the admin panel to that language.

The code I'm using:

```
   <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

The value I get on the site (with English admin panel):

```
   <html lang="en_GB">
```

The value I want to get with the English admin panel:

```
   <html lang="de">
```

My site uses a folder for the language not a sub domain. So the German site is: http://localhost/de/

Comment: Did you change the language for the user? The `lang` attribute in `wp-admin` is defined by the language of the logged in user.

Comment: @fischi No we only have one user. That user always wants the admin page to be English, but now I need to manage to get the lang attribute to go to DE/SE etc depending on the site the visitors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed. I made a small script to get this working.

Because it was a multi language site I just named the site's to the language they should be in. So the English page is named English, German page is called German etc. Made a small php script to check what the page name is so a variable will fill this one in.

PHP code:

```
# Check language of page
$currentLang = get_bloginfo(); 

if ($currentLang == 'English') {
   $htmlLang = "en-GB";
}
elseif ($currentLang == 'German') {
   $htmlLang = "de";
}
# etc
```